# Cannot Access Zoom In and Layer Control in Leaflet

Tags: css, leaflet

I am currently working on a web project on Gazetteer using leaflet.  There were issues in accessing the zoom in and layer control buttons.  The layer control button is at the top right and the zoom in button is at the top left.  Even if the zoom level is not at the maximum, the zoom in button is inaccessible.  It happens whatever tile provider I use (e.g. OpenStreetMap, Esri).  I am using Leaflet Version 1.9.3.

I need to user the dropdown menu to select a country.  I have tried various positions in the id of map, but do not know what is going on.

Here is my CSS Code

```
#map {
    position: absolute;
    font-family: inherit;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100vw;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

/* Select Container */
#selContainer {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 11px 0;
}

/* Select Country */
#selCountry {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Here is my HTML Code

```
<span id="selContainer">
        <select id="selCountry" name="selCountry" class="form-select shadow-sm"></select>
</span>
```

Comment: The best way is to show an example somewhere http://codepen.io/. This error has nothing to do with maps, just a little knowledge of css, I suppose. Remove from selector #selContainer width: 100%; this should fix clicking on items on the map.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move your zoom control to another position you need to disable it and add it again.

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    maxZoom: 24,
    minZoom: 0,
    zoomControl: false//removes default zoom control
});

L.control.zoom({
    position: 'bottomright'//topleft, topright, bottomleft, bottomright
}).addTo(map);
```

If you cannot zoom close enough it may be because your tile layers have maxZoom value. You can solve it by adding maxNativeZoom to them.

```
var osm = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', 
{
    maxZoom: 24,//Zoom you want to be able to scale in
    maxNativeZoom: 22, //max zoom level of tile provider
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; OpenStreetMap contributors'
});
```

To add layer control to another position you need to set it.

```
var layerControl = L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps, {position: 'topright'}).addTo(map);
```

I cannot understand what you want to do with the dropdown. Can you provide some details?